# Google SpreadSheet API and Powershell - Convert to CSV

Tags: powershell, google-sheets, google-api

I have the following spreadsheet which requires authentication:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wDD_Xm8IQYuYNefv9cOJ_7afTLImHgYA05pfN3qY63E

Using the following URL in a browser automatically converts it to CSV and downloads it:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wDD_Xm8IQYuYNefv9cOJ_7afTLImHgYA05pfN3qY63E/export?format=csv

I'm trying to do the same using Powershell.
I have managed to acquire an Access Token from googleapi using the following function:

```
function Get-AccessToken{

    $RefreshTokenParams = @{
        client_id=$clientId;
        client_secret=$secret;
        refresh_token=$refreshToken;
        grant_type=’refresh_token’;
    }

    $RefreshedToken = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri “https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token” -Method POST -Body $refreshTokenParams -ErrorAction Stop | ConvertFrom-Json

    return ($refreshedToken.access_token)

}

$ClientID = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzlobe.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$Secret = "sssssssssssssssssssssss";
$RedirectURI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
$AuthorizationCode = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$AccessToken = Get-AccessToken
```

Now my question is how do I use Invoke-Command to access the link provided earlier along with my access token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With powershell, you want to download the spreadsheet as a CSV file using the access token. And you have already been able to use the access token. If my understanding is correct, how about this script?

#### Script :

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wDD_Xm8IQYuYNefv9cOJ_7afTLImHgYA05pfN3qY63E/export?format=csv&access_token=### access token ###" -OutFile "### filename.csv ###"
```

#### Note :

- When you download the file, if the error occurs, please confirm the following points.

  - Whether Drive API was enabled at API console.
  - Whether `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` was included in the scopes.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.