# DL CSV from Google sheets using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, download

1. I have a Google sheet where I have published a CSV to the web.
2. I am trying to use PowerShell to download the CSV.
3. After the CSV downloads I log the event in a the log file with datestamp.
4. I use Windows Task Scheduler to do this daily.

I have tried to use the code below, and it seems to work if I copy/paste it into PowerShell, but when I double-click to run it, I get errors.

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile(“https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pub?gid=xxxx&single=true&output=csv”,“C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxx\sent_ordes.txt")

function Get-TimeStamp {
    return "[{0:MM/dd/yy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)
}

Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Sent Orders Powershell run " | Out-File 
C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\Sent_Orders.log -Append
```

Comment: Avoid typographic quotes in scripts. And the `Out-File` statement should not be line-wrapped. For further help please show the actual error(s) you're getting. [Edit] your question to do so. Do not post them as comments.

Comment: Ansgar is right about `out-file` and its parameters being split across lines - it will not parse as you intended. You can split commands and parameters across lines with a back-tick character for line-continuation, but it's more common in Powershell to break long lines after the `|` character and indent subsequent lines. It's also easier to read, in my opinion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google SpreadSheet API and Powershell - Convert to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226810/google-spreadsheet-api-and-powershell-convert-to-csv)

Comment: This is a one-liner in a simple nutshell.
`invoke-webrequest -Uri "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/export?format=csv" -OutFile "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxx\sent_ordes.txt"`

Comment: thanks drew that worked perfectly!